# Undefined foreach variable laravel

Tags: php, laravel

hello guys im having a problem with passing variable from my controller to views, as it does not identify its variable, here is my code:

**RegisterController.php**

```
use App\angkatan;
public function index()
    {            
        $select = Angkatan::all();
        return view('/auth/register')->with('name', $select);
    }
```

My Route

**web.php**

```
Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@index');
```

and my view

**register**

```
@foreach($name as $ps)
@endforeach
```

the error say

```
Undefined variable: name (0)
```

im very thankful if anyone can help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just passing the wrong way `$select` variable to your view.

when you use `Illuminate\View\View::with` method you should pass an associative array which as `key => value` pairs

```
  return view('/auth/register')->with(['name' => $select]);
```

You can also use `compact` which allows to pass variable which are accessible inside of the scope of your controller to the view and the string passed as argument to that function will be the name of variable accessible inside of the view file

```
$select = Angkatan::all();
return view('/auth/register', compact('select'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass the variable in this way to the view. You have to pass an array in the second parameter of the `with()` method - it should be something like this:

```
return view('greeting', ['name' => 'James']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    return view('/auth/register', ['name' => $select]);
```

you can pass a second massive parameter to the view,
and also in with method, you need to pass massive as I remember.